# Inverted Solid OpenGL lights?

Tags: normals, opengl

When i opened up my blender file it suddenly inverted all the lightings of the Solid OpenGl lights and whatsoever. I tried to fix it up but it still wouldn't..!
-- Added Explanation as to my reply to someone's comment below:

I'm new to blender so i can't explain much what's going on. When we make a model from scratch, it becomes all gray cause that's the basic color right? Awhile ago when i opened up my blender file it suddenly turned black.. I tried to ignore it and made the leg part, the leg is now gray but the head is still black. When i tried to move the direction lights, the head became gray and the leg became black.. ( I don't know if that made any sense)
[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.. Could you explain what is going on in the screenshot?

Comment: Are the normals of the model facing outside?

Comment: @gandalf3 sorry if it isn't clear. I'm new to blender so i can't explain much what's going on. When we make a model from scratch, it becomes all gray cause that's the basic color right? Awhile ago when i opened up my blender file it suddenly turned black.. I tried to ignore it and made the leg part, the leg is now gray but the head is still black. When i tried to move the direction lights, the head became gray and the leg became black.. ( I don't know if that made any sense)

Comment: @user2859 i'm sure the normals are facing outside o-o.

Comment: Try to select all vertices with A in edit mode and hit Ctrl N.

Comment: @user2859 whoa! Thank you! that worked! What is Ctrl N for?

Comment: @CaptainYang It recalculates the normals, ensuring that they are all pointing consistently outwards if possible.

Comment: @gandalf3 Ohh! I see! Thanks for the help :D

Comment: @user2859 Ohhh! Okay! Thanks for the help :D